# notifyDataSetChanged does not get triggered even I called twice

Tags: android, database

I know that data is inserted in the database , and it is listed correctly but the notifydatasetchanges doesn't works , the list view doesn't get refreshed, so I have to restart my activity....

```
 Cursor c = db.selectAll();
            final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            adapter=new MyContactsAdapter(this, c);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            db.insertInTable("asd","asd"); 
            //insertion in table works, I am sure, cause when I start the activity the new values are listed

    //this the part that doesn't works
        ((MyContactsAdapter)lll.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    lll.refreshDrawableState();





    private class MyContactsAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
            private Cursor mCursor;
            private Context mContext;
            private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

            public MyContactsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
              super(context, cursor, true);
              mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
              mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
              TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
              t.setText(cursor.getString( 0 ));

              t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
              t.setText(cursor.getString(1));

            }

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
              final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
              return view;
            }
        }//adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something like, From your code,

```
    Cursor c;
       @Override
       onCreate(.... {    

       setContentView(...);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         db.insertInTable("asd","asd");
         c = db.selectAll();
        adapter=new MyContactsAdapter(this, c);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

       // some button  click...
       button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            db.insertInTable("xyz","xyz");
                      c = db.selectAll();

             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Try this, Let see what happen...

Comment: I got the same in my code after the insertion I have  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but nothing is get updated, I got a felling that my adapter have some bug, that prevent the view from refreshing....

Comment: You have to just check the values of cursor after insertion of data also put debug point in your adapter's bindView() or newView() if notifyDataSetChanged() called then your execution pointer comes in that methods.